# CSS div with span that is stuck to top?

Tags: css

I'm still new to CSS but I've been trying to find the answer to this problem for a couple of days now and I just cannot hit on the right site or search phrase to uncover the information. Or I am just not getting what I'm reading.

What I want is to have like a title bar across the top of the DIV. I'll have some elements that are children to this DIV and then one or more DIVs .insertAfter'd each other. These title bar DIVs will also be used to collapse and expand to hide and show their children if that makes any difference.

How would I do that with a CSS class? Like class="titleDiv" then

.titleDiv {
  text: left align;
  span: right align;
}

```
<div>Title Text Left Aligned  <span>Item Count Right Aligned</span>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
</div>
<div>Title Text Left Aligned  <span>Item Count Right Aligned</span>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
</div>
<div>Title Text Left Aligned  <span>Item Count Right Aligned</span>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the latest stable/release version of Chrome exclusively if that matters.

Comment: "I'm using […] Chrome" No, that shouldn't matter. Your CSS should work on all [modern browsers](http://browsehappy.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are `<element></element>` part of the title bar or of the to-be-expanded window?

I think you should a `DIV` for each whole window and separate `DIV`'s for the title and content. **If the right-aligned elements** in the title **are the least noted**, a `float: right;` for the `SPAN` might be sufficient.

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <!-- left aligned title bar elements -->
        <span style="float: right;">
            <!-- item count -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="window_content">
        <!-- window-contents -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Otherwise**, you may give a `position: relative;` (without `top` or any other distance given) to the title-bar-element. Then you are able to position the `SPAN` absolutely (using `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;`).

Comment: I would use a div for the item count too, since float turns the element into a block anyway. Also I would make .window_content clear floats, just in case. And you didn't actually show any classes being used with CSS...

Comment: @Neil "And you didn't show any classes being used" My intention was only to show an HTML-example, not a working implementation of the whole window. The classes are just added, to see which part was intended for what usage.

Comment: @feeela - If I do it the way I laid it out then I can have one contiguous border around each parent DIV so it looks like an enclosing box for that particular group. If I did it your way how would I keep that enclosing box appearance?

Comment: @feeela - the <element><element> children are divs themselves and they will each contain their own children. They are not part of the title but I envisioned them being child to the parent enclosing div. Does that make sense? That is why I wanted to position the text at the top like a title bar.

Comment: @Darin "an enclosing box for that particular group" What is that group? A group of windows? Then add another wrapper. Or a group of child-items (<element>s) to a specific window? Then you already have the wrapper. Its called 'window_content' in my example.

Comment: @feeela - wow. Why so rude? I think I was pretty specific about the solution I was looking for. "Its not my job to style the windows" if you felt that way why bother participating in this question?

Comment: @feeela - "What is that group?" If you look at my question you can see the parent div - that will have a solid border all the way around and all the children will be inside the border. If I do it the way you are suggesting I loose the border unless I add another div, no?

Comment: position:relative with top+25px also worked for me. Great answer.